# Latent variable model vs Random effects model?

Tags: random-effects-model, latent-variable

What is the difference between a [latent variable model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_variable) and a [random effects model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_effects_model). It appears to me that the idea is to model unobservable variables or heterogeneity in both models? Or, is latent variable model the same thing as random effects models with a different name?

Comment: Do you have specific models in mind? Where did you come across those two seemingly unrelated model classes?

Comment: @hplieninger Those "seemingly unrelated model classes" seem to be actually related. For those interested in their link, I have found these references: [link1](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~hemken/MPlus/Basics/Multilevel/Multilevel.html)  and [link2](http://dbauer.web.unc.edu/files/2014/08/bauer-SAMSI-2004.pdf)

Comment: The second point in this article also might help: http://dustintran.com/blog/on-bayesian-and-frequentist-latent-variables-and-parameters

Comment: I had the same question... but links do not seem to work any longer...